# How to delete everything from git repository?

Tags: git, command-line

Is there a command to delete everything present in a git repository to make it as good as new? By this I mean:

1. no files
2. no comment
3. no revision.

Comment: I would just create a new repository.

Comment: Make a new folder. `git init`

Comment: The only reason I see to try to make an existing git repository empty would be to perform a (obviously malicious) attack on it.

Comment: let me refine my question I need to commit a different project instead of the one present in git

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Do you want to work on a different project?

Comment: Keep in mind that, if other people use this repository, there would be steps they would have to take as well to erase the history and make it "good as new".

Answer (score 3):

It doesnt make any sence to delete everything under your repository.
What you can do it to *"delete"* the old content and create a new repository and then *add* the current content to your new project.

You can do any of the following which suite you the best:

---

#### Delete all the commits

If you want to leave the current content but to *lose* the whole history.
To do it you can simply delete the `.git` folder and then create a new repository.

```
rm -rf .git
git init
```

---

#### Change the url to a new repository

You can change the remote url - the url of the remote server. Simply remove the current one and set a new one. This can be done by editing the `.git/config` or by using the following command:

```
git remote set-url <new_url>
```

---

#### Creating totaly new repository

Delete your remote repository, delete you `.git` folder and then

```
rm -rf .git 
git init
git add -A .
git commit -m "Message"
git add remote origin <url>
git push origin master
```